# Ionic InAppBrowser show err_unknown_url_scheme

Tags: cordova, android-intent, ionic2, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am trying to open a redirected URL (with intent:// protocol) through Cordova InAppBrowser. However, err_unknown_url_scheme has been shown after the redirection.

We have already utilized whitelist to enable protocol.

Our config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="mailto:*" />
<access origin="tel:*" />
<access origin="intent:*" />
<allow-intent href="http:///" />
<allow-intent href="https:///" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="intent:*" />
<allow-navigation href="intent:*" />
```

testing in html

```
<a href="intent://xxxxx">Do Whatever</a>
```

testing through inappbrowser

```
let testUrl = 'intent://xxxxx';
this.iab.create(testUrl, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

[inappbrowser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zziev.png)
Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen on Android and iOS?

Comment: it happens in Android. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I've had that happen on Android devices when the Chrome browser was not installed and enabled. Chrome didn't have to be the default browser, but it had to be there.  That said, I'm using a stack of plugins that you may not be, so it may not be related.

Comment: We have installed Chrome but it still show err_unknown_url_scheme.
May I know any plugins to handle the case of err_unknown_url_scheme?